# Formal Proof for not (p or not q) implies not p and q

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I've been trying to give a formal proof for $$ \lnot \left(p \lor \lnot q\right) \rightarrow \left(\lnot p \land q \right) $$

in deductive system  **N** (natural deduction system) and got stuck. I've started by assuming $$A1 \Rightarrow\lnot \left(p \lor \lnot q\right) $$

and tried to prove by contradiction with 
$$A2 \Rightarrow \left(p \lor \lnot q\right) $$ 
but got stuck. Am I looking at this problem from the wrong point of view? Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Does a truth-table counts as formal proof?

Comment: What is "Deductive System N" in your text?

Comment: N represents the natural deduction system, and truth tables are not accepted

Comment: I meant: how is the natural deduction system defined by *your* texts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $¬(p∨¬q)$ --- premise

2) $p$ --- assumed [a]

3) $p∨¬q$ --- by $\lor$-intro

4) $\bot$ --- contradiction from 1) and 3)

5) $\lnot p$ --- from 4), discharging [a]

6) $\lnot q$ --- assumed [b]

7) $p \lor \lnot q$ --- by $\lor$-intro

8) $\bot$ --- contradiction from 1) and 7)

9) $q$ --- from 6) and 8) by *double Negation*, discharging [b]

> 10) $\lnot p \land q$ --- from 5) and 9) by $\land$-intro
>
> > $¬(p∨¬q) \to (\lnot p \land q)$ --- from 1) and 10 by $\to$-intro.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been trying to wrap my head around this for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i didnt make any mistakes there (I've added an image with my solution).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\lnot(p \lor \lnot q)$

and

$R=\lnot p \land q.$

we want to prove that $S\implies R$

which is equivalent to  $\lnot S \lor R$.

$\lnot S \lor R  \iff$

$(p \lor \lnot q) \lor R \iff$

$(p \lor R) \lor (\lnot q \lor R)  \iff$

$(p \lor (\lnot p \land q)) \lor   (\lnot q \lor (\lnot p \land q)) \iff$

which is always true  .